# Question of calculation on columns in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I need to perform a calculation on the 1st column of a 2d array and  create another array with  the columns of the first array where the second column is greater than the calculated value using column 1. The array shape is(50,2)

So the formula is this:

0.4 * olumn1 − 0.8

and I need to populate a new array with  both columns where column 2 is greater than the  calculated value above

also wondering if there is a better what to phrase the if statements so that I can do it in one statement instead of 2.

i have tried several things. I have the  calculation down now I just need to know how to populate the new array

here is what I have:

```
win =  (.4 *cne_arr[:,0] -.8)
    if (ce_in[:,1]  > win[0:,]).any():
        winrarray[:,1] = ce_in[:,1] 
        if (ce_in[:,1]  > win[0:,]).any():
            winrarray[0:,] =  win[0:,]
```

bu of course that doesn't work. IT gives me the error

with this I get this error message: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50) into shape (50,2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tmp = # the array with shape (50, 2)
col_1 = 0.4 * tmp[:, 0] - 0.8
col_2 = tmp[:, 1]

mask = np.arange(len(col_2))[col_2 > col_1]
col_2[mask] = col_1[mask]

result = np.vstack([col_1, col_2]).T
```